# My First C# Enum, How Do I resolve Error CS0117?

Tags: c#, enums

I am a beginner to C# and have reviewed my class notes, researched online, and even copied some people. I still can't understand what I'm doing wrong in this code. I have tried changing the data type as well from string to integer and still get errors.

> prog.cs(12,57): error CS0117: 'Months' does not contain a definition for `monthNum'
> prog.cs(17,13): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)

I am trying to create an enumeration for months of the year, receive a user input for a number of the month, and output the month name from the enumeration list.

```
using System;

namespace Homework
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter month number >> ");
            string monthNum = Console.ReadLine();
 
            Console.WriteLine(monthNum + " is " + (string)Months.monthNum);
        }
    }
}
 
public enum Months
{
    January = 1,
    February = 2,
    March = 3,
    April = 4,
    May = 5,
    June = 6,
    July = 7,
    August = 8,
    September = 9,
    October = 10,
    November = 11,
    December = 12
}
```

Comment: `((Months)int.Parse(monthNum)).ToString()`

Comment: First you need to parse `monthNum` to an `int` then you can cast it to the enum `(Months)int.Parse(monthNum)`.  Though you should use `int.TryParse` to handle if the value isn't an integer and also add checking that the number is 1-12.

Comment: @madreflection I appreciate the feedback, thank you from a noobie. I'll remember to be as specific as possible next time.

Comment: Take note of Dmitry's edit, too... quoting the error message makes it clear and distinguishable from your description of the problem.

Comment: The standard for naming an `enum` is to use a singular. So, `public enum Month { ... }`.

Comment: You could avoid the `enum` entirely with `int.TryParse(monthNum, out int m) && m >= 1 && m <= 12 ? new DateTime(1970, m, 1).ToString("MMMM") : "Invalid Month"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are another ways, but you can use the `Enum` related methods:

```
if (Enum.TryParse(monthNum, out Months monthEnum) &&
    Enum.IsDefined(monthEnum))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{monthNum} is {monthEnum}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid month");
}
```